# Celery - How to log parent task id?

Tags: python, celery

I want to log the backtrace of sorts of tasks in the logs - can this be done? Results have parents and can even output a graph, but I can't see a parent task or task id in the Task or request itself. Do I have to pass parent's task id manually to each subtask?

Corollary: is it safe to set the task_id to the same value as the parent?

Edit: example code:

```
@app.task()
def root_task(arg):
    if arg:
        subtask.delay(arg)


@app.task()
def subtask(arg):
    import celery
    print(dir(celery.current_task))  # get parent task id here?
    print(dir(celery.current_task.request))  # no parent here either
```

Note that ideally I want to get the calling task id inside a logging filter which obviously doesn't have access to function locals, so no `bind=True` for me either.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to pass parent `task_id` manually.

If you have simple chain like this

```
@app.task()
def task1():
    return('task1')

@app.task()
def task2():
    return('task2')

c = chain(task1.si(), task2.si())
```

You can see parents task id

```
In [17]: r = c()

In [18]: r.task_id
Out[18]: '9c17b0b6-206c-458f-96ca-be23bc20aa9b'

In [19]: r.parent.task_id
Out[19]: 'e1376a29-6052-427c-8c8e-b14abcb58477'
```

`r.parent` has all the required attributes.

Comment: i wasn't clear enough i guess. i have a task that conditionally starts another task using `subtask.delay(...)` - i'd like to log the caller's `task_id` from within the `subtask()` code. i'll edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: @Baczek Since they are not related to each other, you have to pass `task_id`. However, I think it is not a good idea to set task_id same as parent `task_id`.

Comment: what if tast2 function needs 2 params? Thanks in advance.